# npx create-react-app won't work and this is what I get

Tags: reactjs

> I tried updating node and npm and I uninstalled create-react-app globally but I still got this error please help.

Creating a new React app in /Users/mac/Desktop/monsters-rolodex.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

added 1902 packages, and audited 1903 packages in 59s

153 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

27 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 9 high, 2 critical)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

Comment: what did you write in command

Comment: npx create-react-app app-name